# How to stop Assassin's Creed's speech from desynching?

Tags: pc, macos, technical-issues, assassins-creed

It is really annyoing since in cutscenes I spend about half the time watching lips moving and gestures finishing to something said half a minute ago :-(

This problem seems to occur rather often, but all descriptions I found (e.g. [this](http://forum.suprbay.org/showthread.php?tid=34441&pid=108160#pid108160)) mention turning of sound hardware acceleration. However Windows 7 doesn't seem to provide that option. The audio device is an onboard Realtek HD one.

Comment: Yeah, this also happens on the mac. Unfortunately I've found no real solution either!

Comment: @fail badp my question was about the pc version, but since dynamism mentions mac, shouldn't instead the mac tag be added? this certainly doesn't concern xbox...

Comment: I meet this problem too! Although it's not very important to the game, it's still somehow... funny.

Answer (score 2):

*Disable* in-game sound hardware accelaration;
Check for updated drivers for your sound card;
If possible, disable 'surround' on your card's configs - *that did the trick for me*;
Lowering the resolution (don't know why) works sometimes too.

I found these answers a bit ago, when I had the same problem. Disabling surround worked for me.